# VC++ 2012 Additional Dependencies option in both Linker and Librarian

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, properties, linker, static-libraries

So in Visual C++ 2012, I've found an Additional Dependencies property in both the Linker→Input and the Librarian→General property groups.  For a new project, the Linker→Input→Additional Dependencies has a bunch of Windows libraries, and the Librarian→General→Additional Dependencies is empty.  Does it matter where I put my library file names that I'm using for my project?  These are my own libraries I've compiled from other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is used when creating an exe/dll, librarian is used when creating a static library. So for each configuration, only one of them is considered so yes, it matters where you place the dependencies. (btw this is not only for VS2012 but has been like that for most or maybe all previous versions)

Note that there is a reason why by default there are no entries for the librarian: say you have a static lib A which internally references B, you will still need to add B as a dependency of any exe/dll that uses A since dependencies of a static library are not 'linked' into that library.